# c# cant add references

Tags: c#, mysql, database

Good afternoon . I'm doing a project for school with C # , database and mysql. When I try to add the extension mysql.data it is simply not added. I have installed mysql connector , I have seen hundreds of tutorials but when I add the extension as a reference it is marked but is not added . just go back to go add - reference - extensions and we can see it is not checked again. someone can help me please?

Comment: type of project? web forms? windows form? have you clean the project and build? it gives you error when you declare the using like: using MySql.Data;  ?

Comment: The project is in windows form. I created the all project and never blacked out. when I declare "using MySql.Data ; " it is gray (as when it is not being used) . And the reference " MySql.data " is with a yellow exclamation point . And if I am in AddReference it is no longer marked as a reference.

Comment: mmm if it isn't red i think you can use it, have you tryied istantiate a class of mysql.data? it gives you error?

Comment: This has error in all that is related to mysql. Include when i try to instantiate a class of mysql.data